# Is it possible to create a scatterplot that adjusts for controlled variables (e.g. linear regression)

Tags: regression, scatterplot

I am pretty familiar with linear regression analysis, but not about how to generate plots using it (aside from residuals, etc.). I'd like to create a scatter plot of two variables, say depression and gratitude for example, where the values are adjusted for demographic factors (e.g. age, sex, education). I know I can find the relationships using a partial correlation or linear regression, but I'd specifically know whether it's possible to generate a scatterplot when the demographics have been controlled for. I'm using the most recent version of SPSS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. It is generally called a [partial residual plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_residual_plot) and is helpful in assessing the linearity assumption for a given covariate.

First, fit a partial regression model including age, sex, education, etc as covariates.

Then, create a scatter plot using the residuals from the partial regression on the y axis and gratitude on the x axis.

This seems to be [possible in SPSS](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/what-do-partial-regression-plots-represent)